# Calculating the p value for a difference between bootstrapped parameters using 95% confidence intervals

Tags: statistics

I have bootstrapped model fits to some data, using the $2.5$ and $97.5$ percentiles to generate a $95$% confidence interval.

I know that if $95$% confidence intervals do not overlap then there there is a significant difference between values of at least $p<0.05.$ I would like to calculate the exact p values for pairwise comparisons between the following groups:

Group $A:$
Mean $= 0.05113$ LowerCI $= 0.02279$ UpperCI $= 0.07926$

Group $B:$
Mean $= 0.10979$ LowerCI $= 0.07954$ Upper CI $= 0.14352$

Group $C:$
Mean $= 0.10937$ LowerCI $= 0.09400$ Upper CI $= 0.13040$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You cant get exact p values in bootstrapping because you don't know the true underlying null model. However, if you are assuming that the underlying distributions have the same shape, just different locations then for each pairwise comparison, then you want to test the null hypothesis that they came from  the same distribution.

To do this in boostrapping, you need to make a pooled ECDF from the two sets of data you are comparing and then draw two samples from this pooled ECDF and compute the difference in the means of the two samples. Create a distribution of these differences and see where your observed difference in mean falls. The approximate p-value $\approx$ 1-boostrap pecentile.

If you don't want to assume the same distribution but just the same location, then you can center each sample by subtracting the sample average from each datapoint in the sample. Then draw samples from each of these centered datasets and see how the differences are distributed.